# How to get information from Facebook via OAuth2 external login

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, oauth-2.0

I have registered an app at Facebook and want to be able to login via my web application and use the data from the login. To realize this I have the following controller actions (similar to [here](https://gist.github.com/Maarten88/5761358)) for doing a Facebook login:

```
// GET: /Account/ExternalLogin
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, "http://localhost:8080/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?returnUrl=" + returnUrl);
}

//
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{

    //DotNetOpenAuth.FacebookOAuth2.FacebookOAuth2Client.RewriteRequest();
    var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication("http://localhost:8080/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?returnUrl=" + returnUrl);
(...)
}
```

The code works in that the user can login via Facebook via `ExternalLogin` (used as a GET method) and next the `ExternalLoginCallback` is called. Here the result in the `result` variable is always false. Furthermore, it does not contain any data:

[image: Nothing in the result object.]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.